# What were the repercussions of Saddam Hussein's Iraq switching from USD to EUR in 2000?

Tags: iraq, euro, oil, opec

In 2000, Saddam Hussein switched to [selling petroleum in Euros](https://content.time.com/time/subscriber/article/0,33009,998512,00.html). At that time it was considered an financially unwise decision, but [later it was reported to have won Iraq handsome profits](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2003/feb/16/iraq.theeuro).

- How exactly did switching from the USD to EUR make Iraq richer?
- Did Saddam Hussein break any treaty by selling petroleum in Euros?
- How was this change perceived in OPEC?
- Did it influence other OPEC countries to sell petroleum in EUR instead of USD?

Comment: This seems more like an economics question. Currency speculation is a popular topic in finances, but a win is not guaranteed. Surely Saddam Hussein didn't know how the USD or EUR is likely to develop more than anyone else.

Comment: The article you link explains that the Euro was at a low when Saddam started, and after that its value rose. Holding Euros while their value increases is obviously a good thing. There are a lot of other questions here though.

Comment: This might be better suited to Economics SE or History SE.